# R stream data to read function

Tags: r

I have an `input.csv` of numbers. I do some calculations to it, save the output (say, as `temp.csv`), then have to read the temporary output again as input. Let's say, for example, that I have to add 10 to all values in the csv. I then do `dplyr::fread` on `temp.csv` to read it again. Altogether:

**1. input.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Add 10 to all values, then write out to `temp.csv`.

**2. temp.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3
11,12,13
14,15,16
```

3. `temp.csv` is then passed to a custom csv reading function that wraps `fread`, which wrangles the ingested csv into a required format. It still uses `fread` at its core to ingest csvs, though.

Is there a way in R I can directly "stream" the output of step 1 into `fread`, much like Python's `io.stream`, so that I don't have to keep writing out `temp.csv` each time? It just seems so much cleaner to stream text than to write out and read in text files.

Comment: There is something missing here. Why can't you simply do `result1 <- foo(input1); result2 <- bar(result1)`?

Comment: Because the second function that wraps fread() requires a filename (string) as input. Python sometimes gets around this by passing its read functions a stream object instead.

Comment: Why does it require a file name? Can't you change that (would probably the best solution)? If you have to use `fread` (from package data.table, not dplyr): it accepts shell commands or text instead of a file name as input. You should be able to utilize that.